# How to join the multi row value in single row of SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I would like to submit the multiple line item value in single row of SharePoint list.

The result of the actual submitted value in SharePoint list is shown below image:-
[image]

If the column value is equal to last submitted value then not submit in multiple time otherwise submit the value(like- ReqID and VMName column value in given image). The expected result that I would like is shown below image:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, we are currently unable to implement your needs in SharePoint.

[image]

However, you can set the **AprID** column to be a unique value and required column to prevent the creation of the same item in the list.

[image]

[image]